# How to stop homebrew automatically upgrading postgresql

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

The `brew upgrade` command upgrades all packages, so if `postgresql` is installed with homebrew, the package can be upgraded to a new version incompatible with your databases.  How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 4):

Homebrew can be used to pin a package to its existing version, so if you are using version 12, you can pin it using

```
brew pin postgresql@12
```

You need to do this for each major version you are using.  If later on, you wish to upgrade then  you can do

```
brew unpin postgresql@12
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `brew install <some-app>` also upgrades MySQL and Postgres. I just invoked `brew install awsebcli` and brew proceeded to upgrade two versions of Postgres and one of MySQL, none of which I wanted. This is *not expected* and *not desirable* behavior.